# c# (Connect)Stream readasync reads 0 infinitely

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, buffer

Given the following method to read asynchronously from a `Stream` (simplified):

```
private async void WaitForIncomingMessagesAsync()
{
    var responseStream = WebRequest.Create("some url").GetResponse().GetResponseStream(); // onle here in the example

    var buffer = new byte[8192];
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while (IsRunning /*set by other parts of the program*/)
    {
        int receivedDataCount;
        do
        {
            receivedDataCount = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (receivedDataCount != 0)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, receivedDataCount));
            }
        } while (receivedDataCount > 0);

        var receivedDataJson = stringBuilder.ToString();
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stringBuilder.Clear();
    }
}
```

This works fine until I receive the first 'message' over the stream. 
Since then, it will no longer stop at `await` because it always reads 0.

The stream itself must be kept open all the time.

What am I missing? Do I have to reset the stream, flush it or set the position back to 0?

`responseStream.Position = 0;` or `responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`

> throws NotSupportedException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code I suppose that you want to read new messages each time your outer loops runs. If so then your *GetResponse*  should be inside the outer loop otherwise you will never read new data once your internal loop finished iteration over the stream.

```
private async void WaitForIncomingMessagesAsync()
{
    var buffer = new byte[8192];
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while (IsRunning)
    {
        using (var responseStream = WebRequest.Create("some url").GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            int receivedDataCount;
            do
            {
                receivedDataCount = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (receivedDataCount != 0)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, receivedDataCount));
                }
            } while (receivedDataCount > 0);
        }
        var receivedDataJson = stringBuilder.ToString();
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stringBuilder.Clear();
    }
}
```

I also wrapped your response stream into *using (..) {}* construction so you don't have to worry about closing and disposing it manually.

Comment: Yep. That's what I figured out also now :) Thanks